# How to add two tags to one list

Tags: jquery

I woould like to add two queries to one, is this possible? The queries are:

```
 $("#tttag a") and
 $("#tttag span")
```

So, I could write something $(both).each ( function() {});

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use comma seprated **[multiple selector](http://api.jquery.com/multiple-selector/)**.

> Selects the combined results of all the specified selectors.

```
$("#tttag a,#tttag span").each( function() {
  //do something
});
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use any CSS selector in jQuery: `$.each($('#tttag a, #tttag span'), function(){})`